# Create new MongoDB instance based on existing data

Tags: mongodb, docker

i want to dockerize my production application. I've got MongoDB set up on server and I want to remove it, and make a docker container with MongoDB which will work on existing data. I already tested this approach, so i created a docker container which storage is pointed to host storage with existing data. Basically it's the new MongoDB instance which work on data created by previous mongoDB which existed on Host. And it works, so i can query data, my application can connect to this database and so on. My question is, what are the threats to this approach? And if this is even good approach, or when i created new mongoDB instance should i import dump data from previous one ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no right and wrong in this case. It depends on how you want to have it working.

Let's say you left Mongodb running in the cloud.

Is it a development database? If yes, how would you keep coding / testing without access to that?